# DerbyJS for the JVM?

Tags: jvm, meteor, derbyjs

Is there something similar to the DerbyJS stack for the JVM? Or even parts of it (as implemented in Racer/LiveDB/ShareJS).

For example, what framework/libraries would provide synchronization of a model (probably json) across browsers? Or mimic DB in browser with backend sync?

I see PouchDB can sync to a back-end, but then there's no authorization control (AFAICT). Even ignoring db, and just focusing on sync, maybe Atmosphere + ? + Datomic. Seems like somebody has likely done this before on the JVM, but hard to tell how one could piece together a usable framework.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no simple direct answer to your question, there are a number of places that you can get inspiration from or even use in your project

[Play](https://playframework.com) is a rapid development framework on jvm that is closest to real-time app development. In fact it is a core component of [Typesafe Reactive Platform](http://typesafe.com/platform)

[Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) is a real time client server development framework for the jvm

[Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/index.jsf) has got some nice utilities and components that build on Atmosphere to ease up development with JSF

[Restlet](http://restlet.org/) is also a great API framework that allows you to couple your app with a UI framework (that has two way bindings) like Angular

[Lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com) could be worth a look if you don't mind commercial projects.

There are also JVM javascript vm's that you can run javascript natively, like Rhino, Nodyn, Avatarjs, or the other way around with Doppio so that you can utilize a javascript based framework within the jvm environment.